# proving that a relation is an equivalence relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is the question:

> [image]

**My trial: **

1-reflexive . Assume that $a \in X$  as $[a,a] = \{a\}$ which is in $X$ then the relation is transitive.

2-Symmetric. I have a difficulty in this as $[a,b] \neq [b,a].$ could anyone help me in proving this?

3-Transitive.assume that $a \sim b $ and $b \sim c,$ we want to show that $a \sim c.$ by the first assumption $[a,b]$ is totally in $X$ and by the second assumption $[b,c]$ is entirely contained in $X$ then their union $[a, c]$ is entirely contained in $X$.

Could anyone help me in proving 2, please?

Comment: What is the definition of $[a,b]$ when $a >b$?

Comment: There is no such thing as $[a,b]$ if $a>b$ so I think you are supposed to assume $[a,b]$ is the same as $[b,a]$

Comment: The theorem should be $a~b$  iff  $[a,b] \in X$  or $[b,a] \in X $

Comment: @Babydesta - maybe... maybe not. See [Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals): "When $a > b$, all four notations are usually taken to represent the empty set."

Comment: If $[a,b]$ is supposed to mean $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ a\leq x\leq b\}$ then the relationship **is not** symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better formulated as $a \sim b$ iff $[\min(a,b), \max(a,b)] \subseteq X$. This will work regardless of order of $a,b$ as $\min$ and $\max$ are symmetric. As it stands it's confusing and misleading.